# ADF Better way to count the number of files matching a FileMask, in a known folder

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a `Known\Folder` Path.

That folder contains several hundred small txt files.

Generally the filenames are of the form `Prefix_<Code1>_<SubCode2>_<State>.txt`

I want to know how many files there are for a specific value of `Code1`.

I was hoping to use the `GetMetadata` activity, with Path `Known\Folder\Prefix_Value_*.txt`, but that just returns empty set :(

Currently I've got it working with `GetMetadata` on `Known\Folder`, with `childItems` captured, and then a foreach over all the files, with `If` on `@startsWith(file.name, 'Prefix_Value')`.
But that results in hundreds of iterations of the loop, in sequence, and each activity takes ~1 second so it ends up taking ***minutes*** to do this check.

Is there a better way to do this? Either to direclty locate all files matching my mask, or a better way to count the matching elements of a hundreds-of-items array?

Comment: If I had control over the source of the files, I could just get the files to be created as `Known\Folder\<Code1>\Prefix_<SubCode2>_<State>.txt` and then it's easy again. But alas I don't :(

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get the file count directly matching Wildcard in Get Metadata activity by now. You can vote [Get Metadata for Multiple Files Matching Wildcard](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/36066349-get-metadata-for-multiple-files-matching-wildcard) to progress this feature.

If you only want to copy those files, you can use `Wildcard file path`.
[image]

If those files stored in Azure Blob Storage or somewhere that can be got file count with prefix by API, you can use [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity).

Answer (score 2):

Lots of little activities might be expensive if you do it often.

If you only want the count, you can do this in the following hideous way (promise it isn't written in Brainf&ck) ... it relies on the fact that you can use XPATH to scan XML in ADF.  You only need a set-variable activity after your metadata lookup.

Set a variable equal to this - it will contain the number of files with 'Code1' in the name.

```
@{xpath(xml(json(concat('{"files":{',replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems),'[',''),']',''),'{',''),'}',''),',"type":',':'),'"name":',''),'}}'))),'count(/files/*[contains(local-name(),''Code1'')])')}
```

The inner part:

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Get Metadata1').output.childitems),'[',''),']',''),'{',''),'}',''),',"type":',':'),'"name":','')
```

takes the metadata activity's output and strips the []{} parts and the `type` and `name` elements, then

```
json(concat('{"files":{',<the foregoing>,'}}')
```

wraps that up in to a JSON object, with `files` as the outer key and the filenames as inner keys (with text = "file" but that's going to be irrelevant).

Then you can take that JSON, turn it into XML and query the XML.

```
xpath(xml(<the above JSON>), 'count(/files/*[contains(local-name(),''Code1'')])')
```

The XPATH query counts all the elements under /files (which are now our filenames) whose names contain the text 'Code1'.

Comment: lol a horrid thing but it works for now until we get new features!